# Origin of the expression “turn the card” meaning to pass on an opportunity

Tags: american-english, phrase-meaning, phrase-origin, australian-english

I recently dropped the phrase “turn the card” meaning to pass on an opportunity in an [answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/97567/conflicts-of-interest-dilemma-in-the-us/97569?noredirect=1#comment226976_97569) of a sister site. While not a common expression, I would have expected most people that I converse with in person to have understood it.

However, I got this comment: “I've never heard that expression before, is it an Australian thing?”

I don’t know the answer to that question. Is it an Australian thing? Am I, or the commenter, or both, operating in an even smaller bubble?

I suspect it refers to the card game of [Euchre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euchre#Making_trump_2) where the dealer must either take up or turn down the prospective trump. Turning the card (down) is a lost opportunity for the dealer as the choice of trump passes to their opponent and they do not get the benefit of taking up an extra trump card so the metaphor is direct. But I don’t know that for sure either.

Comment: I've never heard or read it in British English. As far as Euchre is concerned, I cannot remember its being popular here in the last 70 years, so terms derived from it are not going to be popular either.

Comment: I can't find any evidence of it in reference books or via web searches. It's possible it was an expression unique to the OP's family or another small group - it's common to have unique family expressions. It might be a variation of another more common expression or just something created from nothing. Euchre is of 19th century American origin, although reputedly derives from a game from Alsace, so it might be a translation but I see no evidence of that. Without some evidence of the expression used in writing, it's going to be hard to provide a better answer than guesswork.

Comment: Can we have some evidence that this usage ever had any currency? I've never heard it either. So far, all we've got is the OP's assurance that ***he's*** familiar with it, but with no written instances, perhaps it's local to a handful of speakers in his linguistic community (a district within Sidney?).

Comment: I've also never heard of it here in America. It does sound like it could have come from a card game, but it's been so long since I played euchre that I have no idea if it could be related.